# Reading several types of data into arrays

Tags: c++

I am having a tough time figuring out the process of reading text files into the program.  Down in the get_answer_key_array, I am trying to read and put only the top line of the text file into an array.

The text file looks something like this:

ABDBCBDBABABCBABCB

Bob Bobby adcad abcbd  bacb

Every text file tested in this program will have the answer key on the first line.  Every line after the first line will have the persons first name, space, last name, space, grades and missing grades will be replaced by a "-" when I get to it.

I am currently working on obtaining the first line and putting it into the answer key array.
I know that once I am done with the first line I can put the persons first name, last name, and answers into three separate parallel arrays.  I am having trouble coming up with the right way to check for that first new line so I can get the answer key.

Alright so now I have changed my get_answer_key_array to obtain all of the arrays I will need.  Currently I am trying to get the top line (the answer key) into the first array of answer_key[].  I have tried to implement  the getline function but am trying to figure out how to only get the top line.  Is it possible to keep my eof() loop yet stop at the first endline to transferthe data of the first line into the array?  Also my
 answer_key[i] = key; needs changed to something else I bet!

I should also mention once I figure out how to get the top line into an array, I want to use this process to get the rest of the data (names and answers) into their own separate arrays via the following workflow:

```
in_stream >> first_name[i] >> last_name[i] >> answers[i];
while(!in_stream.eof() ) {
    i++;
    in_stream >> first_name[i] >> last_name[i] >> answers[i];
}
in_stream.close();
```

START OF PROGRAM BELOW

```
void get_input_file(ifstream &in_stream);  //gets the text file name from the user
void get_arrays(ifstream &in_stream, int answer_key[], string first_name[], string last_name[], int answers[], int &count);  //brings the data from text file into all of the parallel arrays
//void score_grader(int &target, string first_name[], string last_name[], int answers[], int &count, int &score);
//void letter_grade(int &score, int &letter_grade);
//void student_report(int &target, string first_name[], string last_name[], int answers []); 

int main()
{
    ifstream in_stream;
    int answer_key[30], count = 0, score = 0;   //initializing the answer key array up to 30 answers
    string first_name[20];     //initializing the first name array
    string last_name[20];      //initializing the last name array
    int answers[30];          //initializing the answers array

    cout << "Welcome to the Test Grader." << endl;   //welcome message
    get_input_file(in_stream);   //function call to get the file name
    get_arrays(in_stream, answer_key, first_name, last_name, answers, count);  //function call to create the arrays
}


void get_input_file(ifstream &in_stream) {
    string file_name;   //initializing the file name string

    do {
        cout << "Enter the file name you would like to import the data from: " << endl;  //asks user to input name of file
        cin >> file_name;           //user types name of file
        in_stream.open(file_name.c_str());      //program opens the stream

        if(in_stream.fail()) {
            cout << "Error finding file, try again.\n";  //if failed, asks user for file name again
            continue;   //continues back to the do loop
        }
        break;
    } while(true);

    cout << "File Obtained: " << file_name << endl;  //alerts user of file success with printed name


}

void get_arrays(ifstream &in_stream, int answer_key[], string first_name[], string last_name[], int answers[], 
int &count) {
    int i = 0;
    string key;  //This will be the storage variable for the first line of text file
    if (in_stream.is_open() ) {     //if the stream is open

        getline(in_stream, key);

        cout << "Testing: " << key << endl;

        while(!in_stream.eof() ) {
            i++;
            in_stream >> first_name[i] >> last_name[i] >> answers[i];
        }
    }
    cout << first_name[1] << " " << last_name[1] << " " << answers[1] << endl;
    in_stream.close();
}
```

Comment: If you need to read in a line of data you should be using `getline`.

Comment: `in_stream >> answer_key[i];` tries to read numbers from the file. Is that really intentional?

Comment: `getline` is used for grabbing a whole line. Afterwards, you can iterate over it to pull out all the chars for the answer key.

Comment: Not really on-topic, but are you forced to use a text file? Using some structured format (e.g.: JSON, XML, CSV,...) would probably make your life easier

Comment: Yeah it has to be a text file.  Also I am looking into getline now! Thank you, I will update once I figure it out.

Comment: I finally have the top line of the text file stored in a temporary string.  Now I need to fix the part after that in order to put the names and scores and their own array (3 arrays).

Comment: I need to start getting the input from the file again starting with the second line, any tips?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply read the first line this way

```
void get_answer_key_array(ifstream &in_stream, char *answer_key, int &count) {

     in_stream >> answer_key;
     count = strlen(answer_key);
}
```

The answer_key array must be of type char.

And the endline character is '\n' not '/n'

Comment: _"The answer_key array must be of type char."_ I'd rather propose a `std::string`.

Comment: I have changed the structure of this part prior to comment, hopefully for the best?